# What's the difference between 'ignorant' and 'silly'?

Tags: differences

> while an ignorant person will flounder and encounter difficulty

Comment: In Hiberno-English, *ignorant* has another meaning: angry, quick-tempered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ignorance* is lack of knowledge.

> lack of knowledge or information : *he acted in ignorance of basic procedures.*

*Silly* is behaving in a foolish manner, or showing poor judgment.

> having or showing a lack of common sense or judgment; absurd and foolish : *another of his silly jokes* | *“Don't be silly!” she said*

[Both definitions from NOAD]

Comment: I'd add that "ignorant" is always pejorative, and "silly" is often used as a more positive synonym, even though the underlying meaning is still the same. "What an ignorant decision" comes from someone who's just angry. "What a silly decision" comes from more light-hearted conversation or someone not willing to be so blunt about the point.

Comment: @tenfour: I don't think ignorant is always pejorative. Often, yes, but not always.

Comment: Just to add, look at the etymology of *nice*. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=nice&searchmode=none

Comment: I agree with shiny & new: "ignorant" is often used as if it meant "willfully ignorant" and in that sense it is pejorative, but it is not pejorative in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Ignorant" is (at least on the surface) factual, while "silly" is purely an expression of opinion.  For example, my manager makes decisions I consider silly (and sometimes downright stupid), while he thinks them wise (if not brilliant).  But we agree they aren't ignorant decisions: he has all the necessary information before deciding, including my sage advice.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach to shed some light on the difference between *ignorant* and *silly* is to adopt an etymological point of view.

Whereas the origin of *ignorant* is pretty straightforward ("deprived of knowledge" in Latin), that of *silly* is more complex.

The word *silly* has its root in Old English and probably beyond in Proto Indo European.  It comes from Old Germanic *sâlîg* and the associated meanings shifted gradually from...

- "**happy, blissful**" (OE) to
- "**blessed**" (c.1200) to
- "**pious, innocent**" (late 13c) to
- "**simple-minded, lacking in reason**" (late 16c)
- and today even "**foolish**".

So that as others have already mentioned, ignorance is a *lack of knowledge* and silliness a *lack of common sense*.